# Using a query with a datetime cell in spreadsheets

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, formatting, timestamp, google-sheets-query

I need to query a cell that contains a datetime but its formatted by default when I import it to only show the date.

```
31/7/2020 19:18:58 (in reality it's like this)

31/7/2020 (but it shows this)
```

So when I run this query:

```
=QUERY(A5:R10, "select K")
```

It returns only the date no matter what I do:

```
31/07/2020
```

I've tried:

- Options
- Formatted like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" it returns 00:00
- Filter by datetime or timestamp
- Used '"&Text(now(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm"&"' or something like that

The question is:

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do **without** reformatting the imported cells?

link to test it:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14rGPngGvFXGP8txMS2yFo1v4gPcI4K1oYWj_8yt2Uq8/edit?usp=sharing

when I select one cell with F2 it shows the time:

[image: when I select one cell with F2 it shows the time]

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select column B and format it as date time

[image]

---

or without reformating it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(1*(B2:B4&""), "format Col1 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'"))
```

[image]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TEXT(B2:B4, "yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"), "select *"))
```

[image]

Comment: The question is:

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do **without** reformatting the imported cells?

Comment: @FabrizioTvt. yes, that also possible. answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

**Just make sure your cells are formatted as `Automatic`**

If not, **even if** you use the [`format`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#format) clause of the query, the clause will be ignored

[image]